# BLE- Requesting/Sending data from central device to peripheral device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, beacon

I am using [this](http://www.amazon.in/Bluetooth-Anti-Lost-Tracker-Shutter-Finder-BLACK/dp/B01M317USO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1492415223&sr=8-1&keywords=bluetooth+i+antilost) BLE device. I am able to get connected or disconnected from the device programmatically and also i am able to get datas like **battery level, TX power** from the ble peripheral device. Now i want the ble device to **beep** during some cases. so what is the procedure to send or request data from our mobile to the bluetooth device so that the device beeps.

Any code snippet or links will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any way to send data to BLE device ?